# Erro ao acessar campos inputs com cucumber + capybara

Tags: tdd, bdd

Estava escrevendo minhas *steps* para meus testes com o [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails) e os mesmos não estão encontrando os *ids*, *labels* ou *names* dos formulários.
Já olhei vários tutorias na internet e realmente meu problema é muito estranho, pois em todos sempre o problema é a referência, e neste caso, a minha está correta.

**Steps** (O primeiro passo funciona corretamente)

```
Dado(/^que eu esteja na página de criação de eventos$/) do
   visit "/events/new"
end

Quando(/^eu prencho os dados do evento corretamente$/) do
  fill_in "event_name", :with => "Nome do Evento"
end
```

**Parte do formulário que contém o *input***

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :Evento %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control", :required => true  %>
</div>
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :Data_Evento %><br>
  <%= f.date_select :date_event, :class => "form-control", :required => true  %>
</div>
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :Destacar_Evento? %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :detach, {}, "1", "2" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Criei um ambiente para simular o seu código aqui funcionou perfeitamente, veja abaixo a estrutura do projeto:

```
    #./projeto/app.rb    
    #encoding: utf-8  
    require 'sinatra'

    get '/' do
      "home"
    end

    get '/events/new' do
      erb :index
    end

__END__
@@index
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
       <div class="field form-group">
          <label for="event_name">Event Name</label>
          <input name="event_name" id="event_name" type="text"/>
        </div>  
     </form>
  </body>
</html>

#./projeto/features/teste.feature
#language: pt
Funcionalidade: Preencher formulario
Dado que o quadro abaixo   

    Cenário:Preenchendo trecho de código
    Dado que eu esteja na página de criação de eventos
    Quando eu prencho os dados do evento corretamente

#./projeto/features/support/env.rb
#encoding: utf-8
require_relative '../../app'
require "capybara/cucumber"

Capybara.app = Sinatra::Application


#./projeto/features/step_definitions/teste_step.rb
#language: pt
Dado(/^que eu esteja na página de criação de eventos$/) do
    visit "/events/new"
end

Quando(/^eu prencho os dados do evento corretamente$/) do
  fill_in "event_name", :with => "Nome do Evento"
end
```

Os meus testes muitas das vezes, estavam quebrando porque não havia uma rota que funcionasse outra vezes porque o render ( tanto do rails quanto do sinatra ) não encontrava as variaveis não eram localizadas nas tag <%=f.algumacoisa%>, logo não era possivel encontrar os campos ( uma vez que a página não passa pelo processo de renderização ). Derrepente você pode verificar a exitencia de algum dos elementos que você julga essenciais para sua view. Você pode usar query:

```
page.has_xpath?('//table/tr')
```

se o problema persistir, mande os códigos de seu arquivo: env.rb, da views e da feature, ..., etc
Abrasss